# Looping through an array in ASM by pushing parameters before INVOKE

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm working with pushing info on to the stack before invoking a procedure, and I'm not sure what I'm doing, or what I'm doing wrong. I created PrintArray proc which is supposed to simply print out an array.

I call the procedure like this:

```
push OFFSET array
push count ; length of array
push TYPE array
INVOKE PrintArray
```

and then the actual procedure:

```
 PrintArray proc
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp
    pushad  
    mov esi, OFFSET array;[ebp+16]
    mov ecx, 12;[ebp+12] 
    L3: 
         mov eax, [esi]
         call WriteInt
         mov edx, OFFSET endl 
         call WriteString
         add esi, TYPE array; [ebp+8]
    loop L3
    popad               ; restores registers
    pop ebp             ; restores ebp
    INVOKE ShowParams 
PrintArray endp
```

When I try to replace the hard coded numbers (OFFSET array, 12,  and TYPE array) with what I have commented out (i.e. ebp+12), the program crashes. I'm not sure I'm using ebp correctly, but I do the same thing in a procedure that fills the array with user input, and it builds and runs fine.

I don't know if this is related, but even when I hard code the parameters, the output is not correct.  For example, if I input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, it outputs:

131073, 196610, 262147 { ...} 786443, 12. The last number in the array is always correct.

My complete program:

```
 INCLUDE c:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

 ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

 .data      ;// write your data in this section
input BYTE "Enter 12 numbers", 0dh, 0ah, 0
firstdisplay BYTE "Stack after InputArray and ShowParams calls", 0dh, 0ah, 0
seconddisplay BYTE "Stack after CalculateElements and ShowParams calls", 0dh, 0ah, 0
thirddisplay BYTE "Stack after PrintArray and ShowParams calls", 0dh, 0ah, 0
stackparam BYTE "Stack Parameters: ", 0dh, 0ah, "---------------------------", 0dh, 0ah, 0
     address BYTE "Address ", 0
     equals BYTE " = ", 0
    endl BYTE 0dh, 0ah, 0
    count = 12
    array WORD count DUP(?)

 .code          ;// write your program here
  main proc

InputArray PROTO            ; prototypes InputArray procedure
ShowParams PROTO            ; prototypes ShowParams procedure
CalculateElements PROTO     ; prototypes CalculateElements procedure
PrintArray PROTO            ; prototypes PrintArray Procedure 


mov edx, OFFSET input       ; sets the edx to the address of input
call WriteString            ; prints the edx to the screen

push OFFSET array           ; pushes the address of the array to the stack for invoking InputArray
push count                  ; pushes count to the stack for invoking InputArray
push TYPE array             ; pushes the type of the array to the stack for invoking InputArray
INVOKE InputArray           ; pushes parameters to the stack and calls InputArray

mov edx, OFFSET endl 
call WriteString
mov edx, OFFSET seconddisplay
call WriteString
push count
push SIZEOF array
push TYPE array 
push OFFSET array
INVOKE CalculateElements

push OFFSET array
push count
push TYPE array
INVOKE PrintArray

InputArray proc             ; start of InputArray procedure
    push ebp                ; preserves ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    pushad                  ; saves all registers
    mov esi, [ebp+16]    ;offset of array
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]    ;array length 
    L1: 
        call ReadInt
        mov [esi], eax
        add esi, TYPE array;[ebp+8]
    loop L1

    popad               ; restores registers
    pop ebp             ; restores ebp

    mov edx, OFFSET endl 
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET firstdisplay 
    call WriteString
    INVOKE ShowParams
    ret
InputArray endp

ShowParams proc 
    mov edx, OFFSET stackparam 
    call WriteString 
    mov ecx, 8
    L2:
        mov edx, OFFSET address 
        call WriteString 
        mov eax, ebp
        add eax, 4
        call WriteHex
        mov edx, OFFSET equals 
        call WriteString
        mov eax, ebp
        add eax, 8
        call WriteHex 
        add ebp, 4
        mov edx, OFFSET endl 
        call WriteString
    loop L2
    ret

ShowParams endp

CalculateElements proc 
    INVOKE ShowParams
CalculateElements endp 

PrintArray proc
    push ebp 
    pushad
    mov ebp, esp
    mov edx, OFFSET endl 
    call WriteString
    mov esi, OFFSET array;[ebp+16]    offset of array
    mov ecx, count ;[ebp+12]     array length 
    L3: 
         mov eax, [esi]
         call WriteInt
         mov edx, OFFSET endl 
         call WriteString
         add esi, TYPE array; [ebp+8]
    loop L3
    popad               ; restores registers
    pop ebp             ; restores ebp
    mov edx, OFFSET endl 
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET endl 
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET thirddisplay
    call WriteString 
    INVOKE ShowParams 
PrintArray endp
invoke ExitProcess,0

main endp
end main
```

Comment: Please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable example. It would be nice to see how you define your array although I have a suspicion you do it as `array dw 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`. I'm guessing `DW` is the size since 131073 as a double word (32-bit value) is 0x00020001 . One problem is that `mov eax, [esi]` will always attempt to move 4 bytes of data to a 32-bit register even though the array is made of 2-byte (WORD) elements

Comment: If you are using VS 2015, the easiest thing to do is use the debugger and step through the assembly code to view the contents of the registers, stack data etc. Learning to use the debugger is a great asset.

Comment: "post a minimal…" means come up with something as small as you can that still shows the problem, not post your whole program.  Often coming up with that leads you to the problem yourself!

Comment: Another comment specifically requested that I post all the code. If you don't want to deal with my question, just don't

Comment: @JDługosz : I originally requested a minimal example, but OP didn't seem forth coming so I followed up by asking him for the whole thing, which he did. I'll accept responsibility for his complete code being listed. However as is, it should suffice for someone to determine what is wrong. Previously his code snippets were not enough. And that code is not all that long.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that (comments already cleaned up?)  Just "post a minimal example" / "sure, I'll post the whole thing!".

Comment: @JDługosz : yes there was comment cleanup on my part on a couple requests.

Comment: My very first comment explains part of your problem. You are reading a WORD array as if it is DWORDs in PrintArray

Comment: But the code you originally posted is not the same as what you put in your entire program. For instance PrintArray in your original snippets does `push ebp ; mov ebp, esp ; pushad` but in your complete code listing you have `pushad` before `mov ebp, esp` . In that same code you put `popad` `pop ebp` in the middle of your function and not the end, and there is missing `ret`

Comment: You're right, when I change the array type to DWORD it does display the correct numbers when I hard code the info. I've messed around with other registers, but is there an easy way I can change it so that it will work with a WORD array?

Comment: I have been editing, and trying to make it work. The full code I posted matches what I have now.

Comment: Well the original code snippet is correct. you put the `pushad` after `mov ebp, esp`. You need to put the pop's at the end of the PROC and you need to do a `RET` in PrintArray. As well you are missing a `RET` in CalculateElements which will cause some real problems as the code will continue with what is in memory after.

Comment: As for working with a word array in PrintArray you could use `movzx eax, word ptr [esi]` Would move the WORD at _ESI_ into the 32-bit register _EAX_ zero extending it from 16-bit to 32-bits (This assumed unsigned integers). If you are dealing with signed integers you would use `movsx eax, word ptr [esi]` to sign extend the 16-bit word into the 32-bit register.

Comment: Thanks so much, that really helped.